# is this a valid proof ? and is there a simpler proof?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Let $f$ be twice differential function and that $2f(0) = f(1)+f(-1)$, prove that there exists $c \in (-1,1)$ such that $f''(c)=0$

My attempt : Using Taylor series we get that :

$f(1) = f(0) +\frac{f'(0)}{1!} (1-0)^1 +\frac{f''(a)}{2!} (1-0)^2$

$f(-1) = f(0)+\frac{f'(0)}{1!} (-1-0)^1 + \frac{f''(b)}{2!}(-1-0)^2$

Adding together gives $f(1)+f(-1) = 2f(0) +\frac{f''(a)+f''(b)}{2}$

Which is $0 = \frac{f''(a)+f''(b)}{2}$ leading to $f''(a)=-f''(b)$ , now if $f''(a)=0$ then let $c=a$, otherwise WLG $f''(a) < 0 < f''(b)$ so by Darboux theorem the derivative must have the intermediate value property so there is $c$ such that $f''(c)=0$ , first is this proof correct ?

secondly , is there a simpler proof ?

Thanks

Comment: If it is twice differentiable, you only know that $f''$ exists, but you do not have information about continuity of $f''$

Comment: @TitoEliatron true but $f''$ is the derivative of $f'$ (a function) so by Darboux it must satisfy the intermediate value property, it does not need to be continues.

Comment: Hint:  consider $g(x)=f(x)+f(-x)$.  Argue that there must be a solution to $g''(c)=0$.  That $c$ doesn't give you a solution directly, but you can work from there.

Comment: @lulu so my proof is correct ?

Comment: Yes, it looks good.

Comment: Shouldn't there be rest terms for the Taylor series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof looks OK to me.

Attempt.

MVT:

$f(1)-f(0)+f(-1)-f(0)=0;$

$\dfrac{f(1)-f(0)}{1-0}  - \dfrac{f(-1) -f(0)}{-1-0}=0;$

$f'(b)-f'(a)=0$, where

$b \in (0,1), a \in (-1,0).$

With $a <b:$

$\dfrac{f'(b)-f'(a)}{b-a}= f''(c)=0$, $c \in (a,b)$